# How to generate a very big BigInt

Tags: java, rsa, biginteger, bigint

I want to implement RSA, and for that I need to generate `e` which should be `gcd(e, ø(n)) = 1 and 1 < e < ø(n)` and also should be very close in size to  `ø(n)`. My alg. below respects the first two steps, but the generated number is pretty small. How can I generate a bigger one?

```
    // generate random p,q,r on 512 bits
    p = new BigInteger(512, 15, new Random());
    q = new BigInteger(512, 15, new Random());
    r = new BigInteger(512, 15, new Random());

    // calculate n = p*q*r 
    n = p.multiply(q);
    n = n.multiply(r);

    //calculate ø(n) = (p - 1)*(q - 1)*(r - 1) 
    ø_n = p.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    ø_n = ø_n.multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
    ø_n = ø_n.multiply(r.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));

    do {
    e = new BigInteger(2 * 512, new Random());

} while //while e >= ø_n
        ((e.compareTo(ø_n) >= 0)
        || //while gcd(e, ø(n)) != 1
        (e.gcd(ø_n).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) != 0));
```

Check the `while` loop, everything else is just initialisations.

Comment: Note, you can use `BigInteger.ONE`

Comment: Start with a huge offset + random. And then iterate till no common divisors. Dumb algorithm, but evades "intelligent" numbers that everyone knows to try first.

Comment: I'm not well into RSA but shouldn't you pick randoms from `SecureRandom` ?

Comment: Why don't you go down from ø_n? For example, taking `e = ø_n - 1` should not have common divisors with `ø_n`, and it is the biggest one you can get.

Comment: It is not an efficient way from a computational point of view. Knowing e or how to calculate it makes it easy for an attack. I will do like @JoopEggen said, seems a good alternative.

Comment: Now, if so, how can I generate very big `p,q,r`?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc How about multiply two or three System.nanoTime() values and divide them by a random number between Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `BigInteger.probablePrime()` with `SecureRandom`.